# Is the convex hull of closed cones closed?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, convex-hulls

We say $K$ is a cone if $K + K \subseteq K$ and $[0,\infty) K \subseteq K$.

Let $K_i$, $i \leq m$ be closed cones.

Is conv$(\cup_{i=1}^{m}K_i)$ closed?

Comment: Note that $K_i$ must be a cone, otherwise this is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider two circles $C_\pm$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ $$ x^2+(y\pm
1)^2+(z-1)^2=\epsilon^2$$

Define a cone $K_\pm =[0,\infty)\cdot {\rm conv}\ C_\pm$. Then ${\rm
conv}\ K_+\cup K_-$ is not closed.

[old]

(1) If $x_n\in K_1,\ y_n\in K_2$, and if $t_nx_n
+(1-t_n)y_n\rightarrow z,\ t_n\in [0,1]$, then $|x_n|\rightarrow
\infty$ is nontrivial case.

Let $|x_n|=l_nv_n,\ |v_n|=1$. By compactness, we let $v_n
\rightarrow v$. Note that since $K_1$ is a closed cone, so
$[0,\infty) v $ is in $K_1$. Then $X:={\rm conv}\ K_1\cup K_2$ is
closed.

(2) $X$ is cone : If $z\in X$, then $z= tx +(1-t)y,\ x\in K_1,\ y\in K_2$

So $sz =t(sx)+(1-t)(sy) \in X$ so that $[0,\infty) X\subset X$.

If $z'=t'x'+(1-t')y'$, then $$ z+z' = 2\bigg( \frac{1}{2} (tx+t'x') + \frac{1}{2} \{
  (1-t)y+(1-t')y'\}  \bigg) \in X$$

(3) ${\rm conv}\ K_1\cup K_2\cup K_3= {\rm conv}\ \bigg({\rm conv}\ K_1\cup K_2\bigg)\cup K_3$ so that we complete the proof.

Comment: X is no cone or am I mistaken?
Because $(0,0,1) \in X$ but $(0,0,2) \not\in X$.
That's why I don't believe this answers the question.

Comment: Yes. And $[0,\infty)\cdot X$ is a cone.

Comment: But I can not see how that is a contradiction, by assumption $K_i$ is both a cone and closed.

Comment: Hence if this is meant to disprove the theorem using one single cone $K_1 = [0, \infty) X$ it does not satisfy the assumption.

Comment: You are right. I rewrite the answer.

Comment: I have one last question what if both $x_n$ and $y_n$ converge to infinity?

Comment: I rewrite the answer.